# From mysql CLI is there a way to get the explain plan for a query sourced from a file?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-execution-plan

From MySQL CLI is there a way to get the execution plan of a query sourced from a file?

Assuming the following query in a file `some-sql.sql`

```
select *
from table
```

Called via:

```
mysql> source some-sql.sql
```

Is there a way to obtain an execution plan for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'explain' clause as first line in .sql file.